# crystal reports export to excel cutting off rows

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-export

I am using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 in an ASP.NET 4.0 web forms application.  I have set the report to export in ExcelDataOnly.  The report in the builder runs properly and returns thousands of rows.  When I export it to Excel I am only getting 145 rows!  Does anyone have any idea why this might be?  I have no null values in any columns so it is not that.  I am setting my content type to application/vnd.ms-excel and I think this is correct, so I am at a loss!!!

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was saved data in the report.  No matter what I did I could only get the exact same 145 rows.  In the end, I recreated the report and now it works perfectly.  I have no idea why the data was trapped in that state, but since recreating fixed it, it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you have checked/ selected the option of saving the data with the report. You can go to File--> Below Save AS is the option of selecting the Data to be saved with the Report. Pls uncheck the option and see if it helps.

HTH